# Git installation on Solaris 8

Tags: git

How do I install Git on Solaris 8?

The instructions on the [downloads page](http://git-scm.com/download/linux) only talks about installation on Solaris 11.
Can I get the steps for Solaris 8?

My OS details:

```
>uname -a
>SunOS 5.8 Generic_127721-03 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-880
```

Comment: Do you have any compiler installed? If so, you _should_ be able to build from source.

Comment: Are you serious about Solaris 8 ?. It is VERY old and effectively ceased its life (from Sun's point of view) in April 2009.

Comment: Yep, few of these machines are still on Solaris 8. Not looking for a upgrade in next 8 - 10 months. So need steps to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to compile git and all its dependencies from source, and you need a C compiler for that.  Solaris does not ship with one.  In the old days, gcc could be downloaded in an old version which could be used to bootstrap a new one, and you can then use that to compile what you need.  This may take you some time to get right if you are not familiar with the process.

Another approach that might work for you, is to use jgit instead (requires Java).

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide

The easiest is most likely to download jgit.sh from http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/download/ and try it out.

Comment: "Solaris does not ship with one".  Yes and no to that one. Solaris has shipped with GCC as part of default install since 2005. The problem is that OP is using Solaris 8. .. which didn't have a compiler installed by default if I remember correctly.

Comment: Solaris 8 is from 2000.  I do not believe gcc was included back then and CC was an additional purchase.  Took a few years more before they started targeting developers instead of production systems.

Answer (score 2):

There are repositories making binaries of open source software available for Solaris. For example, [OpenCSW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCSW) has [CSWgit](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWgit/). However, they [stopped supporting Solaris 8 back in 2010](http://lists.opencsw.org/pipermail/announce/2010-March/000143.html). After first shipping in 2000, as of 2013 Solaris 8 has [reached End of Service Life](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/4271-Less-known-Solaris-Features-Long-support-cycles.html), and has been effectively [unsupported since 2009](https://blogs.oracle.com/jimmo/entry/solaris_8_end_of_service).